# How can I create a cross-table by multiple variables in R?

Tags: r, gtsummary

I have a dummy dataset `df` which contains data on the treatment, disease grade and survival outcome of 50 people.

```
library(Hmisc)

# Generate initial cases.

set.seed(123)
n <- 50

df <- data.frame(
  treatment = sample(0:1, n, replace = TRUE),
  grade = sample(0:1, n, replace = TRUE),
  death = sample(0:1, n, replace = TRUE)
)

# Add labels to columns.

label(df$treatment) <- "Drug Intervention"
label(df$grade) <- "Cancer Grade"
label(df$death) <- "Death Occurrence"

# Factor the values.

df$treatment <- factor(df$treatment, levels = c(0, 1), labels = c("Drug A", "Drug B"))
df$grade <- factor(df$grade, levels = c(0, 1), labels = c("Grade 1", "Grade 2"))
df$death <- factor(df$death, levels = c(0, 1), labels = c("Survived", "Died"))
```

I want to generate a 2 x 3 cross table which shows the number of people who survived by grade and treatment. I am using `tbl_strata()` and `tbl_summary()` from gtsummary to do this.

This code is getting close to the desired outcome:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)

df %>% 
  tbl_strata(
    strata = grade,
    ~.x %>%
      tbl_summary(
        by = death,
        percent = "row"
      ))
```

Which produces a plot that looks like this:

| Characteristic | Grade 1 Survived, N = 10 | Grade 1 Died, N = 17 | Grade 2 Survived, N = 9 | Grade 2 Died, N = 14 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Treatment |  |  |  |  |
| Drug A | 5 (28%) | 13 (72%) | 5 (42%) | 7 (58%) |
| Drug B | 5 (56%) | 4 (44%) | 4 (36%) | 7 (64%) |

However the desired output is:

| Treatment | Grade 1 Died | Grade 2 Died | P-Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Drug A | 13 (72%) | 7 (58%) | 0.46 |
| Drug B | 4 (44%) | 7 (64%) | 0.65 |

**How can I use gtsummary to filter out/collapse the 'Survived` columns to simplify the table, and is it possible to add a Fisher's exact p-value for the relationship between death and grade (for the two separate drugs)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to accomplish this. You could filter out individuals who survived since you're only interested in death occurrences, then use tbl_strata() to stratify by treatment rather than grade. Finally, inside tbl_strata(), you can use tbl_summary() to summarize by grade and calculate percentages and use add_p() for your p-values (or whichever method of p-value calculation you prefer).

Here is an example of the structure I am thinking of:

```
df_filtered <- df %>% 
  filter(death == "Died")
table_output <- df_filtered %>%
  tbl_strata(
    strata = treatment,
    .f = ~ .x %>%
      tbl_summary(
        by = grade,
        missing = "no"
      ) %>%
      add_n() %>% # Add counts
      modify_header(label = "**Grade**") %>% # Modify the header
      add_p(test = list(all_continuous() ~ "fisher.test")) # Add Fisher's exact test p-value
  )
print(table_output)
```

Another option is to use `tbl_strata(strata = treatment)` to stratify by treatment, and create separate tables for Drug A and Drug B.

To get your count and percentage format, you can use `statistic = list(all_categorical() ~ "{n} ({p}%)")`.

And you can specify Fisher's exact explicitly as well: `add_p(test = all_categorical() ~ "fisher")`.

This way, your code might look something like this:

```
df %>%
  tbl_strata(
    strata = treatment,
    ~.x %>%
      tbl_summary(
        by = grade,
        statistic = list(all_categorical() ~ "{n} ({p}%)"),
        missing = "no"
      ) %>%
      add_p(test = all_categorical() ~ "fisher.test")
  )
```

You can further modify various aspects of formatting like this:

```
   %>% modify_header(stat_by = "Grade")
   %>% as_gt() %>%  
       tbl_caption(
         caption =  "Captions"
       )
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. I think in your second code block, should it be `"fisher.test"` instead of `"fisher"`? For both of these examples, the Survived row is retained in the final output and I am hoping to remove it .. would adding `value = list(death ~ "Died")` into the tbl_summary() resolve this?

Comment: @JayBee Yes, it should be fisher.test like the first example. I've updated it.

Comment: @JayBee Yes, I believe you're correct about the adding value = list ... and also this may be another way: "df_filtered <- df %>% 
  filter(death == "Died")"

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to other packages besides `gtsummary`, you can use `table1` here:

```
pvalue <- function(x, ...) {
  y <- unlist(x)
  g <- factor(rep(1:length(x), times=sapply(x, length)))
  p <- chisq.test(table(unlist(x), g))$p.value
  c("", sub("<", "&lt;", format.pval(p, digits = 3, eps = 0.001)))
}

table1::table1(~ treatment | grade, data = df[df$death == "Died",],
               overall = FALSE,
               extra.col = list(`P-value` = pvalue))
```

[image]

Or if you want it to explicitly say, "Death":

```
table1::table1(~ treatment | grade, data = df[df$death == "Died",],
               overall = FALSE,
               extra.col = list(`P-value` = pvalue),
               caption = "Death")
```

[image]